# AWS ACM and Route53 - 2 hosted zones with same name, how to handle cert validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have 2 hosted zones in 2 different AWS accounts with identical domain name `prod.example.com`:

```
acc1
acc2
```

acc1 has hosted zone `prod.example.com` is in registrar and all public requests go through there

acc2 also has hosted zone  `prod.example.com` that is ***not*** in registrar.

acc1 has cert `prod.example.com` in ACM that works and is currently used.

I tried creating same `prod.example.com` in ACM acc2 but validation has been pending already for 2+ hours.

Do I have to add DNS record from acc2 ACM to hosted zone in acc1? If yes, will it screw up anything? If not, what am I missing in order to validate prod.example.com in ACM acc2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple *public* hosted zones with the same domain name. You can only have one authoritative (in the registrar) public hosted zone with a given domain name. The other hosted zone might as well not exist because DNS records in a public hosted zone disconnected from the registrar are not resolvable.

You *can* have multiple private hosted zones with the same domain name. However your question is about ACM record validation, and ACM record validation only works with publicly resolvable domain names (public hosted zones).

Comment: thanks, so does this mean I'd want to add DNS verification record for ACM from acc2 to hosted zone in acc1?

Comment: Yes, and you might as well delete the hosted zone in acc2 because it is never going to work.

Comment: I'm actually migrating DNS records to new AWS account, hence identical hosted zone is created there. Everything will be copied to there after updating domain registrar.

Comment: That would have been key information to include in your question. Only one of them can actually be active (configured with your registrar) and working at a time. So you need to copy all the records from one to the other, and them change your registrar to use the other. You can't have a mix of records in each, as only half of them will work.